# how to make css3 and html5 compatible website for all browsers including IE7 and later

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Is there any single framework with which I can build a css3, html5 website that is compatible for all browsers including IE7 and later? Can http://html5boilerplate.com/ boilerplate help me in this?

Comment: why -1 ? is there any problem with this question ?

Comment: It's a misguided question that indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what HTML5 and CSS3 represent and how to approach web development in the modern world, making it difficult to answer in any reasonable way.  It's not a framework which is going to make your site compatible, it's only using features which work in all the browsers you want your site to work in that makes it compatible.  You could use the parts of the HTML5 spec that exist unchanged from HTML4, you could use the parts of CSS3 which exist unchanged from CSS2, would that make it an HTML5 and CSS3 website?

Comment: its question not answer, answer can be misguided not the question i think,  if it is "misunderstanding" that's why i'm here asking for help, jquery makes our life easier regarding compatibility issue with javascirpt so i thought there may be a solution about css3 and html5 major features like header, footer, and css3 shadows, columns, background etc....

Comment: Of course a question can be misguided.  If I asked you "Which variety of custard is the best for repairing shoes?" what would the answer be?  Anyway, you asked why your question was being downvoted, I told you, don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: i'm not convinced, but yes you right Thanks for clarifying why its downvoted...

Comment: @Yasir - I've tried to give you as full an answer as I can. Hope you find it useful. There are lots of tools that can get you part of the way, but the bottom line message is that to achieve what you're asking in the question isn't really possible in the fullest sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will *never* get the IE7 or IE8 rendering engine to achieve full compatibility with HTML5, CSS3, and other modern technologies. They are simply not capable of it.

However there are some hacks, tools and plugins which can get you part of the way.

Tools like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) will help you by allowing you to detect which features are supported, to give your site a chance to work around it.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a great library anyway, but is particularly good in this context because it abstracts a lot of browser differences away from the developer. Some things are easy in most browsers but a real pain in IE; jQuery takes a lot of that kind of stuff and makes it easy regardless.

[Dean Edwards' IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) and [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) are both Javascript libraries that give IE support for lots of the CSS selectors which were missing in older versions. This allows you to write your stylesheets without worrying so much about what IE supports. (IE7.js also fixes a number of IE's other glitches and missing features too)

[CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) is a hack for IE that adds support for CSS `border-radius`, gradients and `box-shadow`.

There are in fact a whole load of hacks along these lines, all aimed at adding features to older versions of IE which it is missing. Modernizr's website has a big list of them here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

However there is one big caveat to all of this. Speed. IE<=8 is a slow browser. It has a slow Javascript engine. Virtually all of these hacks are javascript based. You might get away with running a few of them on any given site, but trying to use enough of them to give IE anything like full support for HTML5 and CSS3 will slow the browser down to the point of being unusable.

There is one other angle to approach this question though, and that's Google's Frame plugin for IE. This basically installs the entire Google Chrome browser engine into IE. The user is still running the IE shell, but the web page is rendered as it would be in an up-to-date version of Chrome.

This sounds great, but of course it isn't perfect. The main down-side of it is that the end user has to install it manually onto their computer, which means that you as a web developer have no real control over whether it's there or not. So its not something you can just add to your site and expect everything to magically work.

Finally, you may also be interested in [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/), which gives browser support tables for various features, allowing you to see at a glance what is and what isn't supported in various versions of each browser.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 is more an umbrella term for a variety of technologies than any one thing or framework. Really, any implementation you do should degrade gracefully-- and that is what makes the site browser compatible. Detect what the browser supports, and then have alternatives that are legacy friendly.

Check out: http://accessites.org/site/2007/02/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/

And: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is an open-source JavaScript library that helps you build the next generation of HTML5 and CSS3-powered websites.

MS is including it in the ASP.net MVC template projects

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't think using modernizr i can achieve the same effect or style on all browser like not even in IE8..here is example by Faruk Ateş http://www.alistapart.com/d/taking-advantage-of-html5-and-css3-with-modernizr/sample-advanced.html image is not rotating, @font-face is not working...

Comment: There's no silver bullet, sorry, Modernizr will help

Answer (score 0):

html5boilerplate won't help you.

As others have said html5 and css3 are very broad terms, there's no framework that implements all of the features provided by both of these. In fact they are not equally supported in browsers that say that they support them. And more, even W3C guys (who write the specs for html5 and css3) are not yet established on what features they will include or what steps will be required to implement them. You get the idea...

But.. if you narrow your requirements to some specific features, like video, audio tags, canvas drawing, nifty css effects, File API, or others, you CAN find frameworks that implement (or try to mimic) them with available technologies in cross-browser manner (more or less).